# Return value of `ref qr/.../`

Tags: perl

[ref](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref):

> But note that `qr//` scalars are created already blessed, so `ref qr/.../` will likely return `Regexp`.

Does "likely" mean, that `ref qr/.../` could also return something other than `Regexp`

Comment: That is quite bizarre phrasing. I can't imagine a situation where that *wouldn't* return `Regexp`, short of truly insane levels of hacking the Perl internals.

Comment: FYI, the addition of this sentence in the doc of `ref` is discussed in [this bug report](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/issues/16801). Spoiler: nobody there seem bothered by the use of "likely".

Comment: Sounds from the linked ticket that it returned `REGEXP` historically? That said, the oldest I have installed, 5.10, returns `Regexp`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it's referring to the fact that someone could rebless the regex, warning that `ref($something) eq 'Regexp'` isn't 100% reliable.

```perl
use 5.010;

my $x = qr/a/;
say ref($x);

bless $x, "Foo";
say ref($x);

say "a" =~ /$x/;
```

```
Regex
Foo
1
```

On top of the above false negative, a false positive is also possible, since someone could bless something that's not a regex into `Regexp`. `reftype` is a better tool.

```perl
use 5.010;

use Scalar::Util qw( reftype );

my $re = bless(qr/a/, "Foo");
my $not = bless({}, "Regexp");

say ref($re),  " - ", reftype($re);
say ref($not), " - ", reftype($not);
```

```
Foo - REGEXP
Regexp - HASH
```